# Can't addEventListener to line tag?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, onclick, addeventlistener

I'm having some issues with adding a click event listener to a `line` tag. The event listeners are working fine for all other tags. I have tested and ensured that the element I am referencing *does* exist when I try to make the event listener. I have also ensured that I am using the correct id. Here is the code. `key = "01"` in this case.

```javascript
console.log('line-' + key);
document.getElementById("line-" + key).addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log("tests");
});
```

```html
<line class="branch" id="line-01" x1="499.46875" y1="380.109375" x2="769" y2="492" stroke="#755331" stroke-width="28.2842712474619" stroke-linecap="round"></line>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: please give a reproducible sample on stackoverlow or codepen. It might be possible that the line is behind another overlapping transparent element, etc. It is not really clear with just the snippet

Comment: I don't believe that `line` is a valid html element.

Comment: @ChrisG https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_line.asp

Comment: @VishalBiswas That is not the problem right now. It is not even making the event listener

Comment: @RileyFitzpatrick Are you sure the element exists *when* you're attempting to add the event listener?  Perhaps try logging out the `document.getElementById`

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, the element exists and is the one I want. I printed out `console.log(document.getElementById...)` and it returned the correct element immediately before attempting to `addEventListener`

Comment: I would agree with Vishal then.  Without seeing more of the code, we cannot determine why it might not be being clicked or added

Comment: So I'm going to leave this open, but I cheated and just set the eventlistener to the parent `svg` tag and used target.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `console.log('line-' + key);` in your example, you are not logging out the element itself, but the `id` that you are going to use to find it.

It is possible that even though the `id` you generate is valid, the element is not on the page when you call `addEventListener`. This might be the case if the element is generated dynamically. Just try calling this instead to check if the element is actually there:

```
console.log(document.getElementById(`line-${ key }`));
```

If you add the event listener to the parent instead, it will be called when clicking any children, even if they are added later, as you can see next:

```js
function handleLineClicked({ target }) {
  if (target.tagName !== 'line') return; 

  const stroke = target.getAttribute('stroke');
  
  console.log(`Clicked element #${ target.id }`);
  
  target.setAttribute('stroke', stroke === '#755331' ? '#FF0000' : '#755331');
}

document.getElementById('svg').addEventListener('click', handleLineClicked);

// Second line added after the event listener has been added to the SVG:

const newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');

newLine.setAttribute('id', 'line2');
newLine.setAttribute('x1', '580');
newLine.setAttribute('y1', '20');
newLine.setAttribute('x2', '20');
newLine.setAttribute('y2', '140');
newLine.setAttribute('stroke', '#FF0000');
newLine.setAttribute('stroke-width', '20');
newLine.setAttribute('stroke-linecap', 'round');

document.getElementById('svg').appendChild(newLine);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 44px !important;
}
```

```html
<svg height="160" width="600" id="svg">
  <line
    id="line1"
    x1="20"
    y1="20"
    x2="580"
    y2="140"
    stroke="#755331"
    stroke-width="20"
    stroke-linecap="round"
  /> 
</svg>
```

Another option to consider is that some other element in your SVG is getting the click, just like what happens if you click where the 2 lines overlap. The second one will always get the click.

Comment: Yes, I have tried printing out the element before calling `addEventListener` and it is created by then and looks how I want.

Comment: Then I would suggest listening to `click` events on the `svg` itself rather than the individual shapes inside it (just like in this example) and if it's still not working, at least you will be able to check which element is actually triggering the click, as you might have some others laying on top of the lines, even if they are not visible.

Comment: Also, check you don't have duplicate ids. That might also cause this issue. You can use `document.querySelectorAll(`#line-${ key }`)` and if it returns more than one element, that's the problem.